# error: If a primary key is annotated with autoGenerate, its type must be int, Integer, long or Long

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, android-room

I tried to create an integer id as primary key,then it asked me to create getter and setter methods and then it wants me to set the id dynamically but I don't want to add an id field in my app and if I have to set id myself what is the use of autoGenerate?

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

@Entity(tableName = "messages")
public class Message {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)


@ColumnInfo(name = "message_date")
private String date;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_timeHour")
private String timeHour;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_timeMinute")
private String timeMinute;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_contactName")
private String contactName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_text")
private String text;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTimeHour() {
    return timeHour;
}

public void setTimeHour(String timeHour) {
    this.timeHour = timeHour;
}

public String getTimeMinute() {
    return timeMinute;
}

public void setTimeMinute(String timeMinute) {
    this.timeMinute = timeMinute;
}

public String getContactName() {
    return contactName;
}

public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

What does it mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you post some code block?

Comment: error is the heading of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have an at least one primary key per your @Entity.

`@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`

You should use this as

`@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 private int id;`

Also, you should have a setter for this id variable so when Room needs to set the primary key value it will use your setter method as your id variable is private. So, now in this case you don't need to set the id at all. Room will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `autoGenerate` property

Your primary key annotation should be like this:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate())

Comment: @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  is causing this error.